# TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (5 given) Keras

Tags: python, keras

I saw another post similar to mine but the fix didn't work. When I run this my model it gives me an exception for this line:

```
model.add(Conv2D(filter=32,kernel_size=5,strides=1,padding='same',activation='relu'))
```

with this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (5 given)
```

I am pretty sure the code is correct but cannot make sense out of the error.

Can someone help me?

Comment: It's `filters`, not `filter`, so it's complaining about the only getting two of the three required arguments (`self`, `filters`, and `kernel_size`). (I agree, the error message could be clearer.)

Comment: https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d

Comment: I would vote to close as a typo, but I think it's worth an answer to explain why there's no error for the unintended `filter` argument.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter you want is `filters`, not `filter`. Since `Conv2D` is defined with `**kwargs`, `filter=32` is treated as an arbitrary keyword argument to be processed later, rather than being flagged as an unrecognized argument.

Once all the arguments have been accounted for, Python sees that only 2 (`self` and `kernel_size`) of the 3 required arguments have been provided, with `filters` being the missing one, leading to the error message you see.